# Why double colon in template argument works?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

While answering one of SO questions I came across code like this:

```
template<class T, class... Ts> void foo();

template <class T, class T::value_type>
void foo() { }
```

It was presented as code specializing `foo` template function, which is not right, but that is not my issue here. I would like to know why does compiler allow construcion like this: `class T::value_type` in the template parameter. I mean, it is pretty clearly wrong, I cannot come up with any situation that scope operator may be part of the argument name  (either template or function). And so I have two qestions:

1. Does standard allow it or is it an overlook in compilers?
2. If standard allows it, why is it so? Are there any use cases?

Comment: I think that `class T::value_type` is an [elaborate type specifier](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier). In this declaration, the second template argument must be a not-type argument of class type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier). Best explained with an example:

```
int main() {
    struct foo {}; // ok
    int foo = 0; // ok

    int test = foo; // ok, refers to variable 'foo'
    foo a; // error, 'foo' refers to variable
    struct foo b; // ok, 'struct' means that name lookup searches for classes only
}
```

In essence, you can think of them (`struct/class`, `enum`) as a more restricted `typename`, as they only allow classes or enums respectively. Also do note that `typename` is allowed in your original example!

```
template<class T, class... Ts> void foo();

template <class T, typename T::value_type> // Ok, value_type needs to be a type
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ it's a non-type template parameter
void foo() { }
```

It is needed when you have a type and a variable with the same name, or to specify what the thing is when you have a dependent name (i.e. in `class T::value_type`, `value_type` is a class, without the `class` before, it would have been a value. Normally, a `typename` is used.)

> I cannot come up with any situation that scope operator may be part of the argument name

Your only thinking of type template parameters here; non-type template parameters can very well use a scope operator to name the type.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong: this `class T::value_type` is just unused template parameter of type `T::value_type`, right?

Comment: @bartop it's unnamed too, yes :)